# DeLorme USB GPS into Raspberry Pi using Python

Tags: python, gps

I have a DeLorme Earthmate LT-40 USB GPS device that I used years ago with a Windows XP program. Out of curiosity I plugged it into my Raspberry Pi to see if I could read the data. I've managed to see data using sudo gpsmon at the command prompt so I would like to take this a step further and write a Python program to read the data. Not knowing very much about Python I've searched YouTube and google for possible solutions. It looks like that I need to import pynmea2. I used pip install pynmea2 to install the module. I keep getting

```
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named pynmea2"
```

when I try to run my script. I tried to reinstall pynmea2 again which gave me

```
Requirement already satisfied: pynmea2 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages(1.15.0).
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The problem is usually that the Python installation to which you added the library is not the same Python installation as the one used to execute the program. As an aside, I would recommend against using your system's Python, in favour of virtual environments or similar tools.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That is a possibility since I do have both 2.7 and 3.8 installed. I don't know what you mean by virtual environments or similar tools. A virtual drive?

Answer (score 1):

I have the older version LT-20 of that GPS and usually it presents itself as ttyUSB0 (in my case) when I plug it on Raspberry.

Just do a dmesg command to see in which port it is being recognized, then you can do a cat /dev/ttyUSB0 command and you see all the messages coming from your GPS. The messages start with a $GP for each type of frame. See detailed $GP description at: http://aprs.gids.nl/nmea/ .

Then from your python program, you can open /dev/ttyUSB0 as a file (as read only) and handle each frame and interpetting it according to its format.

Best regards
Flavio